# VueJS: How will I loop through an array of objects, when the properties of the object is variable

Tags: html, css, vue.js, vuejs3

I have an array of objects that I want to loop through and display as a matrix. However, the properties of the said object will not be fixed but maybe changing from time to time.

Like this

```
[
  {
    location: "Japan",
    webhookStatus: "Up",
    authenticationStatus: "Down",
    indexingStatus: "Under Maintenance"
  },
  {
    location: "USA",
    webhookStatus: "Up",
    indexingStatus: "Under Maintenance"
  },
  {
    location: "Japan",
    webhookStatus: "Up",
    authenticationStatus: "Up",
    indexingStatus: "Down"
  },
  {
    location: "Japan",
    webhookStatus: "Up",
    authenticationStatus: "Down",
    indexingStatus: "Under Maintenance",
    databaseStatus: "Down"
  }
]
```

And I need to display this on a matrix display like a grid or a table.

I have can loop through the array using `v-for` but I also need to iterate through the properties and value of the object even though it will be changing from time to time.

Any thoughts would be appreciated

Comment: Then it's a matter of doing a nested `v-for`: shouldn't that do what you want to achieve? `v-for` supports [array](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/list.html#mapping-an-array-to-elements-with-v-for) and [object](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/list.html#v-for-with-an-object) iteration

Answer (score 0):

You can return the entries in the object as an array using `Object.entries()`.

So, in javascript you can use

```
Object.entries(obj).forEach(entry => {
  const [key, value] = entry;
  console.log(key, value);
});
```

and with v-for in vue you could write something like

```
<div v-for="(key, value, index) in Object.entries(obj)">
{{ index }} {{ key }} {{ value }}
</div>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries